# Data that is vs Data stored vs Stored data

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Which of the following is correct?

Data that is stored on your computer will be encrypted if ....

Data stored on your computer will be encrypted if ...

Stored data on your computer will be encrypted if ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiktionary has the following usage note for the word *data*: "This word is more often used as an uncountable noun with a singular verb than as a plural noun with singular *datum*."

So it is correct to use the word *data* with the singular verb *is* as in your first sentence.

In the second sentence you simply omit "that is", but it is common practice. Wiktionary has the following usage note for the word *that*: "*That* can be used to introduce subordinate clauses, but can just as easily be omitted."

In the third sentence it seems like you want to put more emphasis on the word *stored*.

But gramatically I don't see any problem with any of them.

Answer (score 1):

All are fine to me. It means same thing. But I'd prefer "Stored data on your computer will be encrypted if ...." over the other 2.

hope it helps.